# How to view a data in a respond in post method

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Here is my code after login button clicked....Server sends a response with all details of the user(`email` , `password`, `name`, `user-type`..)..

I want to show the `user-type` in my page..How can i extract only user-type from the `response.json()` and show it to the user???

```
fetch("http://localhost:3000/reg/getuser",

{

    method:"POST",

    headers: 
    {

        "Content-Type": "application/json"

    },
    body:JSON.stringify(user)

})

    .then(function(response)
    {

        if (response.status === 200) 
        {

            console.log(response.json());

            window.alert('Login successfull!')

        } 
        else
        {

            console.log("damn");

            window.alert('Login Failed!')
        }
    })

    .catch(function() 
    {

        console.log('error handling');
    });
```

Comment: This is not reactjs code. Can you post your component code where you want to display user type? What did you try that did not work? What is the console output of the code you shared with us? Thanks

Comment: @Pandaiolo I  want to show the user-type as a header or anyway..I do not know how to get it..here is my console output.......                                                    
  Promise {<resolved>: Array(1)}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]: Array(1)
0:
address: ""
email: "yoshi@my.com"
mobile: "987654"
name: "yoshistu"
password: "$2b$10$og5c.t35dtW/X.o21UAEjOOA1WskE80EpSjK90/yhd5W24N79ZsBa"
type: "customer"
__v: 0
_id: "5ba8ee98c9349a35c422ce70"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)

Answer (score 0):

first declare a global variable for usertype.
than get usertype from response and set global variable like this:

```
var user= JSON.parse(response);
usertype=user.usertype;
```

than you can set wherever you want the usertype data to be seen.

Comment: Looks like the type is just called "type" based on @sandz comment about console output, not "usertype".  so `user.type` is likely what is needed.

Comment: JSON.parse(response) gives an error ..can u explain more?? :(

Comment: @Wyck you are right..but JSON.parse(response) gives an error.. :(

Comment: You still need to convert the response to json: `fetch(/*...*/).then((resp) => resp.json()).then(function(user) { console.log(user.type) });`

Comment: It also gives an error....: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'json' on 'Response': body stream is locked

Comment: @Sandz what have you done eventually? how did you handled it?

Comment: I used jwt token and send the token with the response and in the frontend i decoded the token and get the details easily :)